# How to combine rows with same values in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

How do I combine rows with same values in the first row and put null or space in the rows instead without affecting GROUP BY subject in the select statement? Have a look at what I am trying to achieve and help me.
[image]

My attempted query is:

```
SELECT regd, GROUP_CONCAT(name order by name SEPARATOR ' ') as name,
 subject, sc, fm FROM table GROUP BY regd, subject
```

Comment: Why would you want to "put null or space in the rows"? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to export in this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest that you handle this in code rather than at the DB level!

But, if you absolutely must do it all in a query, you could try [ranking over partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881990/rank-function-in-mysql-with-order-by-clause) with the `regd` column being the partition. Your expected output has rather arbitrarily ordered rows within each `regd`.

This query will order by `subject` within each `regd`:

```
select t.regd,
case when r=1 then t.name else null end as name,
t.subject,
t.sc,t.fm
from
(
 select tt.*,
 case when regd = @curRegd then @rank := @rank +1 else @rank:=1 end as r,
 @curRegd := tt.regd
 from table tt
 join (SELECT @curRegd := 0,@rank:=0) r
 order by regd,subject
) t
```

Finally, based on your stored data example, it seems like no aggregation i.e. `GROUP BY` clause, is necessary here.

Comment: Nice answer, looks like it could work, though I strongly agree with handling that in code rather than in MySQL.

Comment: extraordinary. this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much. It's a big help.