# in sql, how to make a rank column based on the value of another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

say I wish to create a table like following:

```
user   score   rank
a      100     2   
b      200     1
c      50      3
d      50      3
```

How exactly do I create a `rank` column in which it updates with the new entry of record with `score`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rank function in MySQL with Order By clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881990/rank-function-in-mysql-with-order-by-clause)

Comment: Typically, you wouldn't store this in the database

Comment: @Strawberry how would I do it then?

Comment: Well, either calculate it on the fly, or in your application level code (e.g. PHP, javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small table, the easiest way is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.score > t.score
       ) as rank
from t 
order by score desc;
```

Note:  this implements "rank" as per the `rank()` window function available in most databases.